# Transmission Swap (automatic to manual) on a 2011 Ford Fusion

Tags: ford, transmission, swap

I would like to swap from an automatic to manual transmission on my 2011 Ford Fusion. I am 100% confident that I can perform this modification if I am able to find the proper components and a decent resource on correctly modifying the computer.

I am unable to find a "2011 ford fusion manual transmission" online, likely due to the face that a manual fusion of this year seems to be rare. Am I SOL or is there a transmission from another car that will work?

Any resources on how to safely reprogram the computer would be helpful.

Any information on acquiring parts for my specific vehicle would be appreciated. I'm not really sure how to get started. It seems as though this would be a pretty easy swap on a different car.

Comment: Basically anything is possible in theory depending on how creative you are and also how much time and money you are able to pour into this.  But, generally, it's going to be a tough job just swapping a Fusion manual in place of a Fusion automatic.  Going to a "foreign" transmission is going to require making a way for it to fit and to mate up with the engine.  Things like this are done but usually by people who have crazy machinist skills.

Comment: You should at least definitely be able to expand your search to 2010 - 2012 Fusions, as those years are all essentially identical. Hope that helps you find a transmission.

Comment: In the title, you say "automatic to manual." In your text, you say "manual to automatic." The rest of your text supports the title, but you probably should make it consistent!